# PyTorch equivalent to Tensorflow's tf.keras.dot() in terms of behaviour?

Tags: python, pytorch

In tensorflow, if you have 2 tensors of shape NxTxD and NxDxT respectively (N=batch_size, T=SequenceLength, D=NumberOfFeatures), you can dot them and get an output of NxTxT, as demonstrated below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x1 = np.arange(2 * 4 * 3).reshape(2, 4, 3)
x2 = np.flip(np.arange(2 * 4 * 3).reshape(2, 3, 4), 1).copy()
print(x1.shape, x2.shape)
dotted = tf.keras.layers.Dot(axes=(2, 1))([x1, x2])
print(dotted.shape)
dotted
```

```
(2, 4, 3) (2, 3, 4)
(2, 4, 4)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 4, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[   4,    7,   10,   13],
        [  40,   52,   64,   76],
        [  76,   97,  118,  139],
        [ 112,  142,  172,  202]],

       [[ 616,  655,  694,  733],
        [ 760,  808,  856,  904],
        [ 904,  961, 1018, 1075],
        [1048, 1114, 1180, 1246]]])>
```

If you try to do the same in PyTorch, the result is different:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np

x1 = torch.from_numpy(np.arange(2 * 4 * 3).reshape(2, 4, 3))
x2 = torch.from_numpy(np.flip(np.arange(2 * 4 * 3).reshape(2, 3, 4), 1).copy())
dotted = torch.tensordot(x1, x2, dims=([2], [1]))
print(x1.shape, x2.shape)
print(dotted.shape)
dotted
```

```
torch.Size([2, 4, 3]) torch.Size([2, 3, 4])
torch.Size([2, 4, 2, 4])
tensor([[[[   4,    7,   10,   13],
          [  40,   43,   46,   49]],

         [[  40,   52,   64,   76],
          [ 184,  196,  208,  220]],

         [[  76,   97,  118,  139],
          [ 328,  349,  370,  391]],

         [[ 112,  142,  172,  202],
          [ 472,  502,  532,  562]]],


        [[[ 148,  187,  226,  265],
          [ 616,  655,  694,  733]],

         [[ 184,  232,  280,  328],
          [ 760,  808,  856,  904]],

         [[ 220,  277,  334,  391],
          [ 904,  961, 1018, 1075]],

         [[ 256,  322,  388,  454],
          [1048, 1114, 1180, 1246]]]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

Now, Tensorflow's results exist inside the results that pytorch produces (it's a subset of it).
In fact, tensorflow's results is basically some kind of "diagonal" in higher dimensions.
PyTorch's output is NxTxNxT, so to get exactly the same results as Tensorflow you can do:

```py
torch.stack([dotted[i, :, i, :] for i in range(len(dotted))])
```

```
tensor([[[   4,    7,   10,   13],
         [  40,   52,   64,   76],
         [  76,   97,  118,  139],
         [ 112,  142,  172,  202]],

        [[ 616,  655,  694,  733],
         [ 760,  808,  856,  904],
         [ 904,  961, 1018, 1075],
         [1048, 1114, 1180, 1246]]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

but this doesn't negate the fact that you're both:

1. Allocating memory for a tensor of NxTxNxT instead of NxTxT
2. The computational complexity/time increases dramatically

Is there a way to get the same 3 dimensional results that tensorflow gives from pytorch, without it computing the 4 dimensional tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are looking for batch matrix multiplication (bmm) which multiplies two batches of matrices - the two tensors have to be 3D. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bmm.html